# SQL Command (ORACLE) to add constraint with a name

Tags: sql

What should be the sql command(oracle) to add 'NOT NULL' constraint, with a constraint name, to a column of existing table?

Answer (score 1):

```
 alter table t add constraint my_named_not_null check ( x is not null );
```